# Calculator code in Swift doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, case

I am learning swift, and I watched a lecture from Stanford University, in which the Instructor was teaching write a code for one calculator. But before he finish the code he changed the idea and did the same thing with another code. But I'd like to know how to do that with the previous code who he taught.

The piece of the code which is not working is between the `/* */` comments.
There are 4 operations, the times operator is working, but for the others 3 not.

Thanks in advance! and sorry for my English, I am also learning it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userMiddleTyping:Bool = false

    @IBAction func appendDidit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userMiddleTyping {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        }
        else {
            display.text = digit
            userMiddleTyping = true

        }

    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userMiddleTyping {
            enter()
        }
        switch operation {
            case "×":
                if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * operandStack.removeLast()
                    enter()

            }

     /************ NOT WORKING CODE STARTS HERE **************/
            case "÷":
                 if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                    displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() / operandStack.removeLast()
                    enter()
            }
            case "+":
               if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                    displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() + operandStack.removeLast()
                    enter()
            }
            case "−":
                if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                    displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() - operandStack.removeLast()
                    enter ()
            }
     /************ NOT WORKING CODE ENDS HERE **************/

            default: break


        }

    }


   var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    @IBAction func enter() {
        userMiddleTyping = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)
        print("operandStack \(operandStack)")
    }


    var displayValue:Double {
    get {
        return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
    }
    set{
        display.text = "\(newValue)"
        userMiddleTyping = false

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "not working"? Do you get an error?

Comment: In what way is it not working?